# IN query using LINQ for IEnumerable List of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Struggling to get this right.

So I have a model view which has an `IEnumerable<selectlistitem> BusinessUnits` to bind a listBox with multiselect for the view and I have `IEnumerable<string> selectedBusinessUnit` to hold the selected values.

Once the multiple values are selected and postback to the controller I am struggling to use linq query to check values in database against the `IEnumerable<string> selectedBusinessUnit`. More like a SQL "IN" query.

This is my code:

```
public class ProjectsSearchViewModel
{
        public IEnumerable<string> selectedBusinessUnit { get; set; }  //Selected Revenue Organization (Business Unit)
        [Display(Name = "Business Unit")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BusinessUnits { get; set; } //populate list of business units from database for the listbox
    }
```

// My View

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessUnits, new { @class = "col-md-4 control-label" })
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.selectedBusinessUnit, Model.BusinessUnits, new { @class = "form-control", type = "dropdownlist", size = 5 })
```

// Controller

```
if (projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit != null)
                {                
                    result = result.Where(x => x.Project.Revenue_Organization.Contains(projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit));}
```

It says cannot convert IEnumerable to string

Has anyone managed to do something like this successfully. If so would be keen to know how.

More code

```
 var results = (from project in db.Projects
         join emp in db.Employees
         on project.Project_Manager equals emp.Employee_ID
         select new ProjectsList
         {
             Project = project,
             Employee = emp
         });
```

Revenue_organization is one of the columns (property if you like) in the project table (project object) in case any one is wondering.
so end result i am looking for to get list of projects where revenue_organization **IN** selected list of businessunits

Comment: `result = result.Where(x => x.Project.Revenue_Organization.Contains(projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit));` . `projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit` is IEnumerable<String> you cannot use contains. Change the statement to `result = result.Where(x => x.Project.Revenue_Organization.Contains(projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit.FirstOrDefault()));`

Comment: What is the type of `Revenue_Organization` property ?

Comment: @shyu the property is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Project.Revenue_Organization` is a string you need to reverse the statement. The collection should contain the string but as you have it written its checking if the string contains the collection (which does not make sense).

```
result = result.Where(x => projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit.Contains(x.Project.Revenue_Organization));}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Contains on the wrong object. It would be the other way around:

```
result = result.Where(x => 
   projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit.Contains( 
   x.Project.Revenue_Organization));
```

I had this assumptions:

projectsSearchViewModel.selectedBusinessUnit is an IEnumerable.
x.Project.Revenue_Organization is a string value (column in db where you want to make "IN" query).